# haskell HUnit tests not working in cabal test

Tags: haskell, testing

I try to run tests for simple haskell project:

this is a cabal section:

```
test-suite tests-main
    type: exitcode-stdio-1.0
    main-is: tests.hs
    build-depends: base,HUnit
    hs-source-dirs: tests , app
    other-modules: MyModule
    default-language: Haskell2010
```

this is tests.hs:

```
module Main where

import Test.HUnit
import MyModule 

-- Create a test case
testWinV1 :: Test
testWinV1 = TestCase (assertEqual "Test1" True (f1 "data1"))

testWinV2 :: Test
testWinV2 = TestCase (assertEqual "Test2" True (f2 "data2"))

-- Create a test suite
tests :: Test
tests =
  TestList
    [ TestLabel "Test 1" testWinV1,
      TestLabel "Test 2" testWinV2
    ]

-- Run the test suite
-- main :: IO Counts
main = do
  runTestTT tests
```

If I run cabal test :

```
Running 1 test suites...
Test suite tests-main: RUNNING...
Test suite tests-main: PASS
...
1 of 1 test suites (1 of 1 test cases) passed.
```

So it run something, but not my tests.. what I am doing wrong?

I try to run my 2 tests, but it run something, but this is not my tests..

Comment: Are you sure that it is not running your tests? What happens if you make one of the tests fail?

Comment: I looks like it does run your test... why do you think It doesn't?

Comment: Yes, nothing is happen, it's just don't see them, I have 2 test it show 1 test in progress

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is happening because the `exitcode-stdio-1.0` test type looks at the exitcode. And it considers each file as a single test even if it contains multiple cases.

You've used the function `runTestTT :: Test -> IO Counts`, which returns the test statistics, but it does not do anything with the exit code.

If you do not want to do any further processing of the statistics and just want to fail when any test failes you should use `runTestTTAndExit :: Test -> IO ()` instead:

```
main :: IO ()
main = runTestTTAndExit tests
```